# Passing location data to another activity in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android application development and i'm stuck in this point:

I have 2 activities:
First one called CurrentLoc and it gets me the current position and after getting the position i click on a button that take me to activity number 2 which called Sms.

What i need to do is that i want to pass the position data that i have received in the first activity to the second activity when i click the button...

Here is my code for the first activity :

```
    public class Tester2Activity extends Activity { 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startService(new Intent(Tester2Activity.this,SS.class));

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService       (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,     mlocListener);


        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widget30);
         button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {

                  Intent hg = new Intent(Tester2Activity.this, Sms.class);
                  startActivity(hg);



        }
    });



        public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            loc.getLatitude();
                       loc.getLongitude();

                  //This is what i want to pass to the other activity when i click on the button


        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 9):

Use the `Intent` extras: you can just copy the location latitude and longitude into the Intent using `Intent.putExtra` before you call `startActivity`.

EDIT: actually, Location is `Parcelable`, so you can pass it directly to the Intent using [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29), like this:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        passToActivity(log);
    }
```

and then define `passToActivity` as

```
void passToActivity(Location loc)
{
   Intent i = new Intent();

   // configure the intent as appropriate

   // add the location data
   i.putExtra("LOCATION", loc);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

and then you can use [getParcelableExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the value in the second Activity.

Comment: Thanks for the help and i did the same but it didn't work and i think the button is the problem...So where do i have to put the onClick for the button...thanks again

Comment: Please see my related question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851013/send-data-from-one-activity-to-another-regularly

Answer (score 1):

In your FirstActivity

```
Intent hg = new Intent(Tester2Activity.this, Sms.class);
hg.putExtra("latitude",""+latitude);
hg.putExtra("longitude",""+longitude);
startActivity(hg);
```

In the Second Activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
             double lat=bundle.getDouble("latitude");
             double lon=bundle.getDouble("longitude");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didn't work because the Intent can't read anything from the onLocationChanged method and i don't know why?????

Comment: You need to call the Intent from onLocationChanged method?You simply can assign values to two variable lat,lon while getting loc.getLatitude() and loc.getLongitude() and onButton click call the activity as i said;

Comment: I tried it but the same problem is still....The onButton click can't read the intent which is (hg) hence i can't start the second activity..Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Rasel Please see my related question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851013/send-data-from-one-activity-to-another-regularly

Comment: You can pass it using outState.putParcelable("key", location)
Cause Location implement Parcelable interface