# Send data from one activity to another regularly

Tags: android, regex, google-maps, android-volley, activity-lifecycle

I get my location in Main Activity regularly by Fused Location Provider each 30 seconds. I don't use service or anything else. i get location just when user is in application.

In Main Activity i have a button that when pressed, goes to the Second Activity and show my current location on the map (By this line: googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)).

**1-** I want to send my location data from Main Activity to Second Activity regularly(each 30 second that onLocationChange method called), to move my current location's marker. How can i send location data regularly? and where i put codes for this? in onChangedLocation method? (**Or it's not necessary at all?** and my location move automatically when it's changed?)

Also, i send my current location to server, in OnLocationChanged method, by Volley library like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocatuionChanged(Location location){
if(location != null)
    sendLocation(location);
}

private void sendLocation(Location location){
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("latitude", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude();
params.put("longitude", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude();
jsonObjReq = new VolleyCustomReq(Method.POST,
URL, params,
new Listener<JSONObject>(){
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
if(response != null)
    if(response.optString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("1")
        showAlertDialog1();
    else if(response.optString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("2")
        showAlertDialog2();
    else if(response.optString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("3")
        showAlertDialog3();
    else if(response.optString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("addNewMarker")
        addNewMarkerOnMapAsDestinationAndMakePathBetweenBothOfYou();
    ...
}
...
}
}
```

If there is a response from server, depending on the response type, i  want to do something; for example show related message to user, add a marker as destination on the map and make path between two markers.

**2-** Does onLocationChanged method works even when we are in another activities?

**3-** If yes, Does AlertDialog can show in every activities? (not only in Main Activity that showAlertDialog method and LocationListener are there).

**4-** Is there better way to handle responses and do related stuffs?

Comment: What actually you want to achieve ? Do you need current location in your entire app even when it's changed? Or anything else ?

Comment: @MAC I want to do LocationListener stuffs in main activity that have 2 fragments(1-main[contain a button to go to map activity]. 2-aboutMe),send my current location that receive each 30 second to map activity to move my current location marker, and wait for response from server in main activity; when response, it's not important which activity i am(aboutMe,mapActivity,Main), i want to do something(that defined in a method in main activity[show a alert-add a destination marker to map activity]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one activity active and running at any time. You might be better off with 2 fragments or just an additional MapView in your MainActivity which you can make visible or gone, instead of having different activities.

Or you use a service, which can run in the background in parallel to any of your Activities.

Comment: A- So why when i'm in second activity, the toast that was in onChangedLocation method, show regularly?! ;;;; B- And what about questions 3 and 4?

Comment: A - I don't know - it might depend on how you start Activity 2 -- I think now, that - if you use the right flags, you might be able to launch it in another process in which case it might actually be possible to run both activities in parallel. In that case you could communicate via Broadcasts (which I would also suggest to use to communicate from Service to Activity.

As of question 4 - the normal way would be to use a Service.

Comment: 1-If i do something like this: onHandleIntent{ intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);... Can i get location in all activities,everytime it changed?; 2-Move my current location marker is automatically or should i do that like this?:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385768/how-to-move-circle-as-my-location-changed-in-google-map-in-android ;3-If i add map to main.xml, if i put visibility of map to gone, can i find it by id and do my STUFF* like route path, and when user press button to show map, set it to visible with added markers,paths,... (that affected by STUFF*) ?

Comment: With a service and broadcasting, you can receive location updates everywhere. For your other questions, you should just try yourself and come back to Stackoverflow if you run into any problems.